# Replace variable value in html template in string format python

Tags: html, python-3.x, templates, boto3, string-formatting

I have a html template on S3 bucket. I downloaded it and convert it to str

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
bytes_buffer = io.BytesIO()
client.download_fileobj(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key, Fileobj=bytes_buffer)
byte_value = bytes_buffer.getvalue()
str_value = byte_value.decode()
```

And the html template have the following format

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><head>
...
    <p style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial;">
        <span style="color: rgb(236, 240, 241); font-size: 14px;">Hi {{name}},</span>
    </p>
...
</body></html>
```

So how can I change the **name** variable **span** tag in template in a python function
Example, if i have the user name in the input, then i want to replace username in Hi {{name}}

Comment: What variable? And what do you want the result to be?

Comment: name variable in <span> tag, I want to change Hi {{name}} to anyname user input

Comment: Have you heard of Jinja? https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#synopsis

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `.replace()`

```
str_value = str_value.replace("{{name}}","Tung Nguyen")
```